# How to open a file inside a Test Project code folder? (Visual Studio 2008 and .NET C#)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

When I run a Test Project on Visual Studio I use the code below to access a file inside the test project code folder

```
var Location = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0].FullyQualifiedName
);
var FileLocation = Path.Combine(
            Location
            ,@"..\..\..\TestProject1\App_Data\data.xml"
            );
```

There is another (and better) way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you saying that you're trying to find the file in the context of a running test itself?  If so you should look at the [TestContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext(VS.80).aspx) object, specifically at the [TestDeploymentDir](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.testdeploymentdir(VS.80).aspx) property.  You should also mark the file as a [DeploymentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.deploymentitemattribute(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: "You should also mark the file as a DeploymentItem." How do I do that?

Comment: By adding the [DeploymentItem] attribute to the test. Dod a Google search for it, but a reasonable start is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable way to get ahold of the deploymetn directory for a VSTS unit test is to use the TestContext class.  This will be automaticcally hooked up if you define a public property of type and name TestContext on a given TestClass

```
private TestContext _context;
public TestContext TestContext { get { return _context;} set { _context = value } }
```

The TestContext class has several members which point to the actual deployment of test code.  I'm unfamiliar with how a web application is deployed but one of the properties on this class should point you to the correct directory.

Comment: Just for the record: it's not a WebApplication.

Comment: Why the App_data folder then?